# TSQL query help needed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

can someone show me how to modify this query to include the corresponding object name for d.depid?

```
select 
    o.name,
    o.id,
    d.depid,
    o.xtype,
    o.crdate
from 
    sysdepends d
    inner join sysobjects o
        on d.id=o.id
where 
    o.id > 100 and 
    d.depid > 100
```

Desired result set table columns are as follows:
o.name,o.id,d.depid,(the corresponding object name ford.depid), o.xtype o.crdate

Comment: What do you mean by `corresponding object name for d.depid`

Comment: Just add second sysobjects by joining with depid? Or use object_name(depid)?

Answer (score 0):

I would just add `OBJECT_NAME ( object_id [, database_id ] )` to your select list like this:

```
SELECT o.NAME
    ,o.id
    ,d.depid
    ,OBJECT_NAME(d.depid) AS ObjectName
    ,o.xtype
    ,o.crdate
FROM sysdepends d
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON d.id = o.id
WHERE o.id > 100
    AND d.depid > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, is use OBJECT_NAME(depid).